# Not supported type: <class 'numpy.float64'>

Tags: dataframe, vector, pyspark, pca

While trying to create dataframe from a dictionary, I am getting type not supported error
key in dictionary is number of components and variance is the output from pca

```
var = list(np.cumsum(100 * pca.explainedVariance.toArray()))
```

[image]

[image: error]

Is there a way I can create a dataframe?

Comment: spark doesn't accept numpy data types. update the type for all elements within the list using `float()`

Answer (score 0):

Spark doesn't handle numpy data types as pointed out by @samkart. You would need to convert them to a python data type like `float` that spark can infer. Also, I have slightly tweaked the input to a list of tuples rather than a dict.

```py
var = [float(x) for x in var]
md1 = list(tuple(zip(num, var)))

result_df = spark.createDataFrame(md1, schema=["num", "var"])
```

Comment: i was able to create dataframe. Thanks.

I converted to numpy to roundthe values. round() function is not working on float. Is theare an alternative function i can use with float

Comment: @ReshmaJoseph, you can easily look these up in the docs (use [.around()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html)).. or through a quick search online!

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark does'nt support numpy datatypes. You can use python's inbuilt FloatType and DoubleType to overcome this issue. So before creating dataframe out of numpy array, convert/create numpy array with **yourarray.astype(FloatType)**